# typedef structure to array of structures

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm sure this is a brain fart, but I'm missing something and a google search doesn't seem to be bringing up anything.

```
struct item
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

typedef item *itemcatalog;
```

So 'itemcatalog' is simply an array of 'item's.

```
const item items[] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

const item *collection = items; // OK
const itemcatalog catalog = items; // "item const *" is incompatible with "itemcatalog"
```

The idea is that "itemcatalog" is more descriptive and shows that an array of items is expected rather than just a pointer to a single item.

EDIT: fix typo.

Comment: try: `itemcatalog t = items;`  or  `itemcatalog collection2 = items;`

Comment: If you want to learn something to use in your professional programming, a standard container is superior in every relevant aspect.

Comment: I don't think a standard container can be used as there is no heap memory available (embedded platform), so things like vector would fail.

Comment: @squidge: You could use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), but I wouldn't fault you for not using it on a low memory board.

Comment: I prefer to not have a typedef in cases like this. It might make sense if it is `std::map<X, <std:vector<Y> >` or something harder to "get right", but in this case, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First, there's a typo:

On the line that fails, you have forgotten to name the object.

```
const itemcatalog collection2 = items;
```

### Now, let's also try to apply const qualifiers to these variables:

When we do this, we still get an error:

```
foo.cc:14:19: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'const itemcatalog' (aka 'item *const') with an lvalue of type 'const item [2]'
const itemcatalog catalog = items;
                  ^         ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

To fix this, we need to realize that we actually need two typedefs in this situation:

```
struct item
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef item *itemcatalog;
typedef const item *constitemcatalog;

const item items[] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

const item *collection = items;
const constitemcatalog collection2 = items;

item mutable_items[] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

const item *collection3 = mutable_items;
const itemcatalog collection4 = mutable_items;
```

On the various collection objects, the `const` we are applying tells us if we can move the pointer. `constitemcatalog` vs `itemcatalog` tells us if we can modify the data the pointer points to.

Comment: Nice description and explanation, thanks :) Accepted and voted up.